# How to allow for "named arguments" in a custom AngularJS filter?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am creating a custom Angular filter and I would like to provide the closest thing possbile to "named arguments" (a la Python), primarily for the purpose of boolean options so as to avoid passing an unreadable sequence of true/false values.

If I only had to consider calling from "raw" javascript I would accept some kind of options object:

```
myFilter(someValue, {
    foo: false,
    bar: true
});
```

However I would like this to be easy to use from within [Angular expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) too. Is it possible to pass objects like this within an expression? If not, or perhaps if it is simply too awkard, what would be a more idiomatic approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah why not, you can use named arguments easily in a filter:

```
app.filter("myFilter", function() {
    return function(item, filterConfig) {

        if (filterConfig.foo) {
            // return something
        } else {
            // return something else
        }
    }
});
```

And usage:

```
{{ myValue | myFilter:{foo:false} }}
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfd486Lm/1/)

Comment: I was looking for a way to use the filter from within an Angular expression; I have updated my question to make this clearer.

Comment: What do you mean with 'an angular expression'?

Comment: The things you put inside double curly braces; see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression. Is there a better term for this?

Comment: Yeah you can use this also in there, see edited answer and added jsfiddle